# How to change button behaviour after click on it? Change "add to cart" button on "remove from cart", and it's behaviour

Tags: javascript, toggle, counter, shopping-cart

I have created a simple functionality for my cart, add the number of items to cart (from the counter). Now I need to make some changes to it, but I don't have idea how to do this. When I click to "add to card", the items go into the cart, then I need this button to change it's behaviour and it's name to "remove from cart", so on it's click it removes the items(listed in counter) from my cart -> and change it's behaviour to the default (add to cart). I need something like toggle it's behaviour, some ideas how can I do this? Thank you a lot !!!

```js
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart'); 


    count = 1;

    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

    minus.onclick = function(){
      if (count === 1) return;
      count-=1;
      amount.innerHTML =count;
    };
 
    button2.onclick = function(){
      cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart">products: </div>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What should cause the button to change its behavior?  (how do you know when it should change from adding items to removing them?).  Also, have you tried changing the text on the button, and implementing the reverse logic of adding items (decrease the total, etc ?)

Comment: It should change it's behaviour after user click 'add to cart', so it must be a button that toggle function on click , from add to cart to delete from card and inverse. I can change it's text name, but not it's behaviour (

Comment: So a person can only ever click the Add to Cart button once, and then it becomes a Remove from Cart button?  Also, you should at least try to implement the reverse logic of removing items from the cart.  Why can't you reduce the total, etc ?

Comment: you could read the text that would tell you what the button should do, then its a case of switch on 'blah...'

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the information if your button is in *add to cart mode* or *remove from cart mode*. You could do that by creating another variable of type `boolean` next to your `count` variable:

```
var count = 1;
var cartIsEmpty = true;
```

Then check it's value when the button is clicked and update it so it always tells you if the cart is empty at the moment. On the way you can change the buttons text too:

```
button2.onclick = function(){
    if (cartIsEmpty === true) {
        cartIsEmpty = false;
        button2.innerHTML = "remove from cart";
        cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
    } else {
        cartIsEmpty = true;
        button2.innerHTML = "add to cart";
        cart.innerHTML = "products:";      
    }
}
```

Full code:

```js
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart'); 


    var count = 1;
    var cartIsEmpty = true;

    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

    minus.onclick = function(){
      if (count === 1) return;
      count-=1;
      amount.innerHTML =count;
    };
 
    button2.onclick = function(){
      if (cartIsEmpty === true) {
        cartIsEmpty = false;
        button2.innerHTML = "remove from cart";
        cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
      } else {
        cartIsEmpty = true;
        button2.innerHTML = "add to cart";
        cart.innerHTML = "products:";      
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart">products: </div>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following keeps track of the current cart count and allows infinite number of add removes. Uses jquery for efficiency purposes. CSS unchanged.

```js
var plus =  document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = $("#cart"); 


    count = 1;
    
    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

    minus.onclick = function(){
      if (count === 1) return;
      count-=1;
      amount.innerHTML =count;
    };
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass( "add" )) {
      cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
       $(this).removeClass("add");
       $(this).addClass("remove");
       $(this).html("remove from cart");
       new_value = parseInt(cart.attr("value")) + count
    }else{
     $(this).removeClass("remove");
      $(this).addClass('add');
      $(this).html("add to cart");
      new_value = parseInt(cart.attr("value")) - count;
    }
    cart.attr("value", new_value);
    cart.text("products: " + new_value);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add" class="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart" value=0 >products: </div>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```